# ci4 not verifying captcha v2 in backend

Tags: codeigniter-4

ci4 contact form with captchav2 not linking with back end to verify captcha

Tried using scripts and tried changing the controller from various tutorials . I also created a g- recaptcha-response input field in a mysql database table to store input .